# List sum too large, throwing overflow exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, math, integer-overflow

I have a list of prime numbers up to 2 000 000. That's a list containing almost 150 000 very large integers. I want a sum of all the numbers in it. Here's a random list of large integers just for demonstration:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(1000000000);
}
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Sum().ToString());
```

I'm getting a "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" exception. I guess the sum is too large, but converting it to Int64 didn't help, it still throws the same exception.

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt64(numbers.Sum()).ToString());
```

I even tried saving the sum into Int64 variable and then using it, but this didn't work either.

```
long sum = numbers.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
```

Is there any data type that can hold this large number, or am I making the mistake somewhere else? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your number may be larger than what `int` can hold. I would try changing it to `long`

Comment: This is a common bug pattern. In all your attempts you change the sum to long, but changing the *sum* to `long` doesn't help because that converts *too late*. That converts the *final sum* to long, but by then it has already overflowed!

Comment: We also see this pattern as: `int x = whatever; double percentage = x / 100;` but `x/100` is *int*, so this converts to double *too late*. What you want is `((double)x)/100` or `x/100.0`, which causes the compiler to insert the conversion for you. There are lots of variations on this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is your answer is over 2.65 billions.
Change the `int` to `Int64`

```
List<Int64> numbers = new List<Int64>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(1000000000);
}
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Sum().ToString());
```

To Clarify an Int has a max value of 2.65 billion roughly and Int64 is in the trillions

Comment: I think this is a better way than doing 150k conversions, even though the integers are alright for the numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try casting to Int64 (long) before getting sum:

```
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Select(x=> (long)x).Sum().ToString());
```

Comment: 150K very large integers probably will overflow even longs.

Comment: This solution requires to convert `int` to `long` 150 000 times. I doubt that it's an optimal solution

Comment: @Steve well then he should implement a custom adding system, for example one that works for strings.

Comment: I was thinking about BigInteger, however I should rethink my comment. Adding 150K times Int.MaxValue doesn't overflow a long MaxValue

Comment: @Fabjan as China Syndrome said its better to choose a `List<long>` instead of `List<int>` but I assumed this is something obvious and OP may already know that. I thought may be this is an example and he can not simply change the type. I have tried to make the least change to OP's code and just correct where it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.

Comment: @Steve I'm sorry, from the example it looks like I have 150k integers with 1 billion value. But their values are only up to almost 2 milion.

Comment: Integers are ok to store them but as @Fabjan noted, using Int64 list is probably the way to go, to avoid a lot of converting.

Comment: Just as a note you need at least 4.3 billion integers to oveflow long (and they would not fit into single array anyway).

Comment: @Steve, Int64.MaxValue / Int32.MaxValue = 4,294,967,298, so no, 150K very large integers are at most 0.00349 % of Int64.MaxValue.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Aggregate` method:

```
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Aggregate(0L, (c, n) => c + n));
```

This overload of `Aggregate` take an accumulator as first argument
Literal `0L` will be treated as `long`, not `int`. This will save you from arithmetic overflow

Answer (score 2):

Conversions from int to long are cheap, sometimes even for free. Lets compare five codes

```
long sum = intArr.Select(x => (long)x).Sum(); // 0.95s

long sum = intArr.Sum(x => (long)x); // 0.95s

long sum = longArr.Sum(); // 0.86s

long sum = 0;
foreach (int x in intArr)
{
    sum += x; // 0.22s
}

long sum = 0;
foreach (long x in longArr)
{
    sum += x; // 0.23s
}
```

elapsed time is for 100M items. As you see, if you care about performace, the conversion is not an issue